# How to plot bar graph based on data from state

Tags: python, pandas

How do I go about getting the average loan amount in column G based on the state in column S?

[image]

How can I specify the state that I want the average of the column for?

This is my code right now.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('Loan_data.csv')

loan = data.iloc[:,6:7].values
state =data.iloc[:,-6]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the averages, create an aggregated dataframe. Then you can select specific states' averages to view from that:

```
agg_df = data.groupby('State',as_index=False).agg({'Loan_Amount': 'mean'})
# View West Virginia's average
agg_df[agg_df['State']=='WV']
```